# Shared Preferences to modify the view of mapView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, settings

i need help from people with more experience than me,i have started not too much time ago to study how to write an application for Android but anyway,i explain the problem.

In my application i want to change the mode to see the map (sat,traffic,streetView) using 3 checkboxPreference. I have created a option menu with only a choise and,this choise,open the layout with the 3 checkbox.

```
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="Sat"
android:title="Satellitare" android:summary="Mappa con vista satellitare"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="Traff"
android:title="Traffico" android:summary="Mappa con vista traffico"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="StrView"
android:title="StreetView" android:summary="Mappa con vista Street View" 
       android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The layout class file Impostazioni.java.

```
package com.drive.info;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Impostazioni extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.menu_navi);
    }

}
```

And in another file Navi.java i have all the code i need to run the map. All function: the map with the base view (no sat or other settings),the option menù and the layout work.

**How can I change the setting of the map using the checkboxes?**

*Thanks to anyone who will help me!*

Comment: You mean, you want to set checkBox value dynamically in code?

Comment: No,i want to control the view of the map with the checkbox. If i check sat,for example,the view of the map switch to satellitar and ec..

Answer (score 0):

Get the `SharedPreferences` object which has the data of your preferences activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Now get the needed values:

```
boolean sat = prefs.getBoolean("Sat", false);
boolean traff = prefs.getBoolean("Traff", false);
boolean streetView = prefs.getBoolean("StrView", false);
```

And set them in your `MapView`:

```
mapView.setSatellite(sat);
mapView.setTraffic(traff);
mapView.setStreetView(streetView);
```

By the way, `setStreetView` is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Street view availability highlighting is no longer supported. This method operates as a no-op.

So I don't using using it will cause any change in the map.

Comment: First of all,too much thanks for your help.
I have used the sharedPreference in the Impostazioni.Java file and,in the same file,i have set the boolean value for each variable (sat,traff,streetview). Next,in the Navi.Java class, i have set the call for the variable but,in this file,cannot recognize the sat,traff and streetView as variable.  I have forgot a passage or what?
Because i have understand the method to call the variable from another activity (in that case the menu) but i don't have undestand why eclipse give me the error.

Comment: If the `sat`, `traff` and `streetView` variables are declared in Impostazioni.java as local variables, you can't access them in Navi.java. Declare and get their values in Navi.java (You can access the shared preferences from everywhere in your app)

Comment: Now the code is ok and in the emulator i have no error,but when i go in the menu and check,for example,the box of satellite,when i return in the main i don't see any change n the map. If i remember correctly when an activity is launched (menu),the first is frozed (navi) and need an ()onResume to refresh the data,is that a case similar? When i turn back from the menu and the navi activity restart,need to call a resume in the code?

Comment: Yea. Read the preferences and update the map view in Navi.java's `onResume`.

Comment: Ok,i have remembered well in my noob situation ehehe

I think the code is:

`@Override
protected void onResume() {
          super onResume();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}`

When i return to the main activity (navi) from the menu,i recall the preference manager